# Login with facebook keeps redirecting after permision confirmation from facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am applying **"Login with facebook"** on my website.

When I click Login with facebook.... It redirects to facebook asking for permission. I click ok. Now after that it keeps redirecting to facebook and my website simultaneously.

I am providing my code below. Can anyone help me finding out where is the mistake that is redirecting ?

Here is my Code:

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start(); 

if ($_SESSION['FBID']): ?>      <!--  After user login  -->

<h1>Hello <?php echo $_SESSION['USERNAME']; ?></h1>

<li><?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?></li>

<div><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>

<?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login --> 

Not Connected
<div><a href="fbconfig.php">Login with Facebook</a></div>

<?php endif ?>
```

**fbconfig.php**

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';  // Include facebook SDK file
//require 'functions.php';  // Include functions
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'APP_ID',   // Facebook App ID 
  'secret' => 'SECRET',  // Facebook App Secret
  'cookie' => true, 
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $fbid = $user_profile['id'];                 // To Get Facebook ID
        $fbuname = $user_profile['username'];  // To Get Facebook Username
        $fbfullname = $user_profile['name']; // To Get Facebook full name
        $femail = $user_profile['email'];    // To Get Facebook email ID
    /* ---- Session Variables -----*/
        $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;           
        $_SESSION['USERNAME'] = $fbuname;
            $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
    //       checkuser($fbid,$fbuname,$fbfullname,$femail);    // To update local DB
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
   $user = null;
  }
}
if ($user) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'     => 'email', // Permissions to request from the user
        ));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide redirect_url(URL of index.php)

```
if ($user) {
    header("Location: index.php");
} else {
 $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope'     => 'email', // Permissions to request from the user
        'redirect_uri' => 'URL of index.php'
        ));
 header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

One more thing, you should not disclose your app_id and app_secret. Remove it asap.

Comment: Ok now it comes to index.php but shows nothing extra on index.php. Means still show the Login with facebook link. Not logout.

Comment: With this URL: http://localhost/facebook/index.php?code=AQAwXra3ApI1A1O0GvMm1l4tFbswTYvhGxSaJydc3M_O4YMdiksaGemsgaysvDuSBTbX3GbRUJO87nTO7228JFSPALfTsTjSvFsQxzDSh8tOKX02pE-GEy-qqI7TjCKCW9GQkB1gr6PDpz3d3dmXF5fendqxbj8BnnLI7h4FR4WMPNEFTtTYGZQObJlMO9LX0pFxtXNg5-sFLngbs9xRBbqs_s0-7Mj8rSZUCER9Uz_IcCOVoqza-9d4DMMyIyFqD8buo5dSx30G3TmaKn_JAk1Ra2R-CsOK6x-O8kWatVqC9vbsJJQjgubAADmPwd2AyQOP2cAdyN4zpzyQADSYgLqf&state=42e388406e0703b46b4a22d02d9e46a7#_=_

Comment: Change index.php to <?php
session_start(); 

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user): 
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

?>      <!--  After user login  -->

<h1>Hello <?php echo $user_profile['name']; ?></h1>

<li><?php echo $_SESSION['FULLNAME']; ?></li>

<div><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>

<?php else: ?>     <!-- Before login --> 

Not Connected
<div><a href="fbconfig.php">Login with Facebook</a></div>

<?php endif ?>

Comment: Its says: Notice: Undefined variable: facebook in D:\localhost\www\1353\index.php on line 4

And

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getUser() on a non-object in D:\localhost\www\1353\index.php on line 4

Comment: Add this at the top :- require 'src/facebook.php';  // Include facebook SDK file
//require 'functions.php';  // Include functions
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '6835932gfh61734019',   // Facebook App ID 
  'secret' => '2206ab8b23csfe46bf8334aa767e986a9888',  // Facebook App Secret
  'cookie' => true, 
));

Comment: These errors are coming even after adding require 'src/facebook.php'

Comment: @AniketSahasrabudhe Remove teh app ID and secret key for privacy.  That's sensitive information.